# What's the short story where the man is sick and tired of advertising?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title and author of this story.  It's just a few pages long and starts with a man on a bus coming home from work looking at the screen on his watch.  His wife is talking to him on the little screen.  Everything in his environment is covered by ads, even the toilet paper.  He finally gets fed up and finds a little room somewhere that he can rent for an exorbitant amount to find some peace - in the room there are no ads, no piped in music, no screens of any kind.

I think the story is by Ray Bradbury but I'm not 100% sure.  It's not in any of my Bradbury collections.

If you know this story, please post the title and author - thank you!

Comment: Before we close this as dupe, shouldn’t we wait for the OP to confirm that the dupe is correct?

Comment: Thank you, it is the same story I was looking for - "The Room" by Ray Russell.

Comment: Bradbury has a similar short story, where a man gets fed up with advertisements and constant noisy electronics and starts destroying anything around him making noise, and this is also a theme present in *Fahrenheit 451* (e.g., "Denham's Dentrifice").

Comment: I'm new here, but this is much more rich in searchable keywords than the duplicate. Wish they could be edited together.